# How does Flyways multiple schemas work?

Tags: flyway

I am trying to figure out how the multiple schemas feature works. Like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262280/flyway-managing-multiple-schemas-doesnt-work), I experiencing that only the first specified schema is actually used. The others are created, but then nothing happens with them again. I don't think I am understanding the feature correctly.

What I want to have happen is to have multiple, identical, schemas in my Postgres database. So in PG I have the schemas: tenant1, tenant2, etc...  Each of these should have identical schemas so I will have a migration script that says `CREATE TABLE users` and in the end I want `tenant1.users` and `tenant2.users`. Effectively this would be the same as putting it in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has now been added to the FAQ: http://flywaydb.org/documentation/faq.html#multiple-schemas

> If you have multiple identical schemas, say one per tenant, invoke Flyway in a loop and change flyway.schemas to match the name of the schema of the current tenant.